# x86 Assembly with gas on linux: multiple definitions of 'main'

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm starting out with programming in Assembly in x86 and I'm following a guide for that. I'm using gas to compile on a linux virtual machine.

I'm trying to run a simple empty program where main routine exits the program immediately. That's the first task in the guide I'm following. My code is saved in a file hello.s and it looks like this:

```
.global main

main:
  movq   %rsp, %rbp
  mov   $0, %rdi
  call   exit
```

In the terminal I navigate to the directory of the file and try to run it like this:

```
gcc -o hello.o hello.s -no-pie ./hello.s
```

I get an error saying:

```
/tmp/cc62hr1F.o: In function 'main':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'main'
/tmp/ccwMutY1.o(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does this error mean and how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, I'm not a fan of that syntax so I don't use gas and am not entirely up to speed, but you do potentially have 2 main labels there...  What happens if you remove one or the other of them?

Comment: Your problem is that you pass `hello.s` twice to the compiler, so it assembles it twice and tries to use it twice to generate a binary, causing the duplicate symbol error you observe.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT/SOLUTION: I figured out what was wrong. In the terminal I should run it like this:

```
gcc -o hello.o hello.s -no-pie
./hello.o
```

These are two seperate commands. I wrote them in one line. And the file to run has to have the extensions .o not .s

Comment: Note that on Linux/UNIX, executable files typically have no file extension. So `gcc -o hello -no-pie hello.s` (also note, options come before operands) would be more correct.  Files suffixed `.o` are *object files* which need to be linked before they can be run.

Comment: There's certainly some option to get .o file from .s (`-c` is for C source, too lazy to verify it works for .s too), but as long as your whole code is in single .s file, you may let the `gcc` to build the binary directly, just like you did. Just don't use `.o` for binary name. Default binary name is `a.out`, unless you specify your own by using `-o <filename>` option.